# Data can't submit through ajax, php and jquery in to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I try to insert data through the ajax, PHP and jquery but the code is not working properly. anyone can help me what is going wrong. even I used serialize() method also but no result.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myform">
      <label>Username</label> <input name="name" type="text">
      <label>Password</label> <input name="password" type="text">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            url: "new.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
              $('form').trigger("reset");
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the new.php it means the PHP code in another file.

```
 <?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'test');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $username=$_POST['name'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];

     $sql="INSERT INTO ourteam(name, position) VALUES ('$username','$password')";
     $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

?>
```

Comment: you forgot to end your if statement. Add a closing `}` at the end of it - you also need to `echo` the `$result` in some way

Comment: *not working properly* not enough to describe your problem .. you can tell us what is the output of `alert(data);`

Comment: Please provide as much information as you can. any errors from error.log, or copied and pasted from your outout is welcomed as an aid to help us help you

Comment: serialize won't include the submit button

Comment: Also: your `serialize()` call will not include `submit` in the arguments list, as a submit button is not treated in the same way as input fields or select elements are. Therefore the property `$_POST['submit']` will never be set in new.php.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that this method expects a response from the server in-order to be able to store data as the server response.

```
success: function(data) {}
```

You can return this data by outputting it using echo, which we will also `json_encode()` for the JS to be able to understand the output.

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'test');

header('Content-Type: application/json'); # Declare what content type we are returning

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

if(empty(array_diff(array('name', 'password'), array_keys($_POST)))) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO ourteam(name, position) VALUES (?, ?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['password']);
    die(json_encode($stmt->execute())); # die() will halt the program here so no other instructions are executed
}
```

I updated your code to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: No result, in alert I give false message nothing more.

Comment: It doesn't provide any error, even I removed the $_POTS['submit'] from new.php but no result just it show false in alert box nothing more